# Python 3.3.2 Testing for keyword in a users input

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword

```
test1=input("This is a test: ")
test1=test1.split()

print(test1)
if ("word1") or ("word2") in test1:
    print("test successful")
elif ("word3") or ("word4") in test1:
    print("test 2 successful")
```

In computer science we are required to build a program which analyses a user input to find what problem they are having. A friend and I have developed this snippet of code which should output a different answer depending on the users input, however if 'word3' or 'word4' are inputted it outputs the answer to 'word1' or 'word2'. Can somebody please tell me what is wrong and how to improve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a bug with your test condition:`"word1" in test1 or "word2" in test1`

Comment: `if "word1" in test1 or "word2" in test1:` .... `if "word3" in text1 or "word4" in test1:`

Comment: what you wrote is equivalent to saying: if "word" exists (which it always does btw as long as it is not an empty string) or if test1 contains "word2" print("test successful").. `or` has priority over `in`